# I want to extract values from my table in php. I have embeded form in my table but I am not able to get values using $_POST

Tags: php

I want to extract values from my table in php. I have embeded form in my table but I am not able to get values using $_POST.I have extracted some information from the database and some as input from the user. Now I want to store the user input in the variable. Can someone please solve this issue?It's urgent.Thanks in advance

```
        <?php
session_start();
include ('connection.php');

include('simple_html_dom.php');
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
        if($result = $link ->query($sql))
        {  
            //echo "success1";
            if($result->num_rows > 0)
            {
                //echo "success2";
                $table = "
                <form method = 'POST'> 
                <table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed'>
  <thead>
    <tr style = 'background-color: white' >
      <th>ID</th>
      <th style = 'text-align: center'>Name</th>
      <th style = 'text-align: center'>Time In</th>
      <th style = 'text-align: center'>Time Out</th>
      <th style = 'text-align: center'>DD</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>";
                while($rows = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
                    $id =  $rows['id'];
                    $name =  $rows['name'];
                   // echo $id;
    $table .=  "<tr style = 'background-color: white'>
      <th scope='row' style = 'vertical-align: middle'>".$id."</th>
      <td scope='row' style = 'vertical-align: middle'>".$name."</td>
      <td scope='row' style = 'vertical-align: middle'><div class='form-group'>
            <input type='time' name='in[".$id."]' class = 'form-control'>
             </div></td>
       <td scope='row' style = 'vertical-align: middle'><div class='form-group'>
            <input type='time' name='out[".$id."]' class = 'form-control'>
             </div></td>
       <td scope='row' style = 'vertical-align: middle'><div class='form-group'>
    <select class='form-control' name = 'dd[".$id."]'>
      <option>YES</option>
      <option>NO</option>
    </select>
  </div></td>

    </tr>";
                        }
               $table .=  "</tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class='form-group'>
            <input type='submit' name = 'submit' id='butt' class= 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 btn btn-primary' value='Submit'>
                 <br>
                    </form>";
                echo $table;
                if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                {
                    var_dump($_POST['in']);
                }

        }
            else
        {
            echo "<div class = 'alert alert-warning'>No employee in the database</div>";
            exit;
        }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div class = 'alert alert-danger'>Unable to run query</div>";
            exit;
        }
?>
```

Comment: How do you submit the form? I see no submit button or input.

Comment: <div class='form-group'>
            <input type='submit' name = 'submit' id='butt' class= 'col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 btn btn-primary' value='Submit'>
                 <br>
                    </form>";
                echo $table;
                if($_POST['submit'])
                {
                    echo $_POST['in'];
                }

Comment: Can you please edit that into your question? Comments aren't suitable for extended pieces of code.

Comment: I am so sorry for that....I edited my code. Can you plz look into it once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code, but none of them should prevent `$_POST['in']` from echoing when you submit the form. But I assume your real problem is not getting *all* the data you need.

First off, you can't have multiple elements with the same name - only the last one's value will be captured when you submit the form if you set it up that way. So you need a way of making every input distinctive, which you can achieve by adding square brackets `[]` to the name. That way, your `$_POST` variable will hold an array. Since you need to know which user the input refers to, you can add the user's id to the name as well:

```
<input type='time' name='in[".$id."]' // and so on, the same goes for 'out' and 'dd'
```

That will make your `$_POST['in']` have the following structure:

```
[$userId => $userInputValue]
```

Since it will be an array, you won't be able to `echo` it to test the contents, change that to `print_r` or `var_dump` (very useful for debugging).

Another modification to make is to check whether a variable is set before checking its value. If you keep it like this:

```
if($_POST['submit'])
```

it will give you an undefined index notice when the form is not submitted. You need to replace it with:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

This says "if the key 'submit' exists in the $_POST array", which is all you need to detect if a form was submitted (the value of the submit element is not relevant here).

If you apply all these changes to your code, you should be able to see all of the input values and then you can use them for further processing (db storage, etc).

Comment: Thanku so much for that sir . I did everything as instructed by you but once i click the submit button, my page is getting refreshed and nothing is being printed. I have edited the code in the question section

Comment: What do you mean by nothing? Not even the table with inputs or the `$_POST` contents?

Comment: $_post is not working. Table is being printed perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

[When i pick date and press select button the table is displayed normally as it connected with ajax call from another page but as soon as i select the second button the page is refreshed and even the table is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxU28.jpg)

ss in the link